# How to inherit another coroutine scope in a custom coroutine scope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android

I was implementing `viewHolderScope` for collecting flows in `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`s. It would start from `onBindViewHolder` and gets cancelled `onRecycleViewHolder`. But along with this requirement, it should also automatically get cancelled when the surrounding `lifecycleScope` ends in case of `Activity` or surrounding `viewLifecycleScope` ends in case of `Fragment`. So, how can I inherit from those scopes?

```
interface ScopeProvider {
    val scope: CoroutineScope
}

val viewHolderScope = CoroutineScope(ScopeProvider.scope.coroutineContext)
```

Does this work as intended?

**Edit:** Since many are asking why I am collecting flows in `ViewHolder`, here I will tell what I was trying to do and why I choose to do that.

I was building a chat application. In that, consider the chats list screen. There I wanted to show if a user is active or not with a green dot (like facebook). For this, if I have to collect flows in `ViewModel`, then I think I *have* to collect flows for all the users in the chats list and not just the ones visible on screen. So I thought instead I could collect flows in `ViewHolder` itself starting `onBind` and ending short after `onRecycle`. Anyway it had a defined lifecycle, and so I thought a `viewHolderScope` can be implemented.

**Edit2:**
Entire flow of user status.

```
<ViewHolder>
viewHolderScope.launch {
    chatStatusObserver.statusFlow(getItem(bindingAdapterPosition)!!).collect {
        // update view
    }
}

<Fragment>
private val chatStatusObserver = object : ChatStatusObserver {

    override fun statusFlow(chat: Chat) = model.statusFlow(chat)
}

<ViewModel>
fun statusFlow(chat: Chat) = when (chat.type) {
    ChatType.PRIVATE -> repo.getUserStatus(chat.receiverId)
    ChatType.GROUP -> repo.getGroupStatus(chat.receiverId)
}

<Repository>
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun getUserStatus(userId: String) = callbackFlow {

    val userStatusListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val timestamp = snapshot.getValue<Long>()!!
            val status =
                if (timestamp == -1L) UserOnline
                else UserOffline(timestamp)
            trySend(status).onClosed {
                throw it ?: ClosedSendChannelException("Channel was closed normally")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            trySend(Unavailable).onClosed {
                throw it ?: ClosedSendChannelException("Channel was closed normally")
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: ${error.code} : ${error.message}", error.toException())
        }
    }

    trySend(Pending).onClosed {
        throw it ?: ClosedSendChannelException("Channel was closed normally")
    }

    Firebase.database.reference.child(NODE_STATUS).child(userId)
        .addValueEventListener(userStatusListener)

    awaitClose {
        Firebase.database.reference.child(NODE_STATUS).child(userId)
            .removeEventListener(userStatusListener)
    }
}
```

Apart from the above flow, there is only this in `ViewModel`, which gets paged flow from `RoomDao` -> `Repository` and passes it to `Fragment` -> `PagedAdapter`.

```
val pagedChatsFlow = repo.getPagedChatsFlow().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: Any special reason for collecting flow inside view holder? What functionality are you trying to build?

Comment: I recommend you to submit already collected data to view holders (for example, from view model or presenter), you should avoid extending their responsibility

Comment: Its completely bad solution. As Steyrix said you should create UiModels in your VM or presenter and set them into your adapter.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, I have updated my question. Please check and tell what could work in this case.

Comment: @Steyrix, I have updated my question. Please check and tell what could work in this case.

Comment: @rost, I have updated my question. Please check and tell what could work in this case.

Comment: Can you add some code of ViewModel in the question related to this users flow? I am pretty sure there exists a better way to meet your requirements without creating a viewHolderScope.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Done! check.

Comment: In your current code, it looks like you are calling repository functions (indirectly) from your ViewHolder. This will lead to a lot of unnecessary network calls. You will be requesting status for one user multiple times.

Comment: @ArpitShukla yeah, you are right. Can you tell me a better way please..

Comment: I can't think of an easy way here. One way can be to maintain a `Map<String, Flow<UserState>>`. Now whenever you get a request for `Flow<UserState>`, first check in the map, if the userId exists return that flow, else request repo for the flow and save it the map.

Comment: @ArpitShukla but still, where to collect it?

Comment: You should combine your room db chats flow and user status flow in the ViewModel itself to generate a flow of list of `ChatItem`. And then feed this list of `ChatItem` to the adapter. It contains all data related to chat as well as user online status. But since you have a paging flow, you will have to think about how to combine these flow together.